# CREATESTRUCT error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int c:\x\dcd\dcdchild.h 22 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to modify an project that was written in an old version of Visual Studio.  I now use Visual Studio 2010.  When I opened the project it was automatically converted to 2010 format.  However, when I build it I get the following error:

> Error 1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\x\dcd\dcdchild.h 22  1

The file in question is quite small:

```
// dcdchild.h : header file
//

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDCDChildWnd frame

class CDCDChildWnd : public CMDIChildWnd
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CDCDChildWnd)
protected:
    CDCDChildWnd();         // protected constructor used by dynamic creation

// Attributes
public:

// Operations
public:

// Implementation
protected:
    virtual ~CDCDChildWnd();
    virtual CDCDChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CDCDChildWnd)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The line in question is:

```
virtual CDCDChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
```

I have looked up the definition of CREATESTRUCT and it is:

```
typedef struct tagCREATESTRUCT {
  LPVOID    lpCreateParams;
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  HMENU     hMenu;
  HWND      hwndParent;
  int       cy;
  int       cx;
  int       y;
  int       x;
  LONG      style;
  LPCTSTR   lpszName;
  LPCTSTR   lpszClass;
  DWORD     dwExStyle;
} CREATESTRUCT, *LPCREATESTRUCT;
```

So it does indeed include variable type int.  The question is, how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `virtual CDCDChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);` is invalid. It should look like this:

```
virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method has no return type declared:

```
virtual CDCDChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
```

You probably meant:

```
virtual BOOL CDCDChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
```

(The error message is referring to the fact that in early versions of C you were allowed to omit the return type, in which case `int` was assumed - this is not allowed in C++ however.)